# Binary Tree: Node frequency count for 0, 1, or 2 children

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have an assignment:

> You’re given the root node of a binary tree T. We distinguish between 3 types of nodes in T: nodes with 0 children, nodes with 1 child, and nodes with 2 children. Determine, for each type, the number of nodes in T. Return your result as an integer array of length 3.

I am given a Java file that generates random test cases for this algorithm.

I am only allowed to create one function to do all of this. I am not allowed to pass any additional parameters into the method below. I am also not allowed to make any other modifications outside of the function that I create.

In the file, there is a base case already inserted. I have been told to traverse the tree in post-order, using recursion.

I am aware of the current issues with my code. But I don’t know how to fix them.

My current code is as follows:

```
private static int[] problem1(Node root) {

    int[] arr = new int[3];

    if (root == null) {
        return new int[] {
            -1, // nodes with 0 children
            -1, // nodes with 1 child
            -1 // nodes with 2 children
        };
    }
    //problem1(root.left);
    //problem1(root.right);

    if (root.left != null && root.right != null) {
        arr[2]++;
        problem1(root.left);
        problem1(root.right);
    } else if (root.left != null && root.right == null) {
        arr[1]++;
        problem1(root.left);
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right != null) {
        arr[1]++;
        problem1(root.right);
    } else {
        arr[0]++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The Node class is defined as:

```
static class Node {
            public int value;
            public Node left;
            public Node right;
        }
```

Comment: First off, are you allowed to return a static variable that is declared in the class where your method belongs to? Does your method strictly should only return a local array? And do you also mind sharing the definition of the `Node` class? We need more context!

Comment: @AmalK I have added the node class definition to my post. As long as I don't modify anything outside of my function, but it has to be an int array.

Comment: Please don't add things like "SOLVED" to titles when your question has been answered. Accepting an answer is the way to indicate your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Node root = new Node(1, new Node(2, null, null), new Node(3, null, null));
        int[] counts = problem1(root);
        System.out.println(counts[0]); // 2 node(s) with 0 children
        System.out.println(counts[1]); // 0 node(s) with 1 children
        System.out.println(counts[2]); // 1 node(s) with 2 children
    }

    // recursively count number of childs for each root/node. Post-order 
    // traversing means both left and right node will be traversed before
    // any computations.
    public static int[] problem1(Node root) {
        // always need a base-case to stop recursive call.
        if(root == null) {
            return new int[]{0,0,0};
        }

        // post-order traversing
        int[] leftChildCounts = problem1(root.left);
        int[] rightChildCounts = problem1(root.right);

        int [] counts = new int[]{0,0,0};
        counts[0] = leftChildCounts[0] + rightChildCounts[0];
        counts[1] = leftChildCounts[1] + rightChildCounts[1];
        counts[2] = leftChildCounts[2] + rightChildCounts[2];

        if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            counts[0]++;
        } else if(root.left != null && root.right != null) {
            counts[2]++;
        } else {
            counts[1]++;
        }        
        return counts;
    }
}

public class Node {
    int value;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right) {
        this.value = 0; 
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }       
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I’m only allowed to have the node as the only parameter passed into the function. The function has to return an integer array.

Comment: @CyberknightMk1 then does your professor allow any global variables? ;)

Comment: @CyberknightMk1 okay, I've updated my answer according to your constraints.

Comment: That did the trick, I had made multiple arrays previously, but I never set them equal to the recursive call. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've come pretty close, the only thing you should fix is handling the array of result.

Currently you create a new `arr` that is supposed to stored the results for every call of `problem1` and its wrong because this new array has nothing to do with previously created arrays.

Consider to create it outside the call of `problem1` method. You can always pass it as an additional parameter and "accumulate" the result (there is even a term called "accumulator" for this, so `arr` will be an accumulator).

Think also about the return result (hint: with the accumulator approach you don't really need to return anything)

Since its an assignment, obviously I won't give a full solution leaving to you all the fun ;)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can’t change the method header. I’m only allowed to have a single node passed in. How would I create it outside of the call of problem1?

Comment: @CyberknightMk1 just create another function with 2 parameters (root, array) to be called by problem1.

Comment: In my original post, I stated that I can only have one function to do this. Sorry, I’ll make it more clear.

Comment: My professor won’t allow us to add helper functions.

Comment: oh - I've missed all the party of comments here ;) The suggestions given by @Roy Lee are obviously coming from a seasoned software developer this is how we would have solved it in a "real life" :) Now you really should ask your professor about this point - probably he has missed this. You still have an option to use a "static field" `arr` in the class that contains the definition of `static int[] problem1(Node root)` but it will be ugly. Bottom line, we've both pointed on the issue with the current implementation, but we can't change the assignment :)